# Python remove text if same of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I want to drop in my dataframe the text in a column if it starts with the same text that is in another column.
Example of dataframe:

```
name        var1
John Smith  John Smith Hello world
Mary Jane   Mary Jane Python is cool
James Bond  My name is James Bond
Peter Pan   Nothing happens here
```

Dataframe that I want:

```
name        var1
John Smith  Hello world
Mary Jane   Python is cool
James Bond  My name is James Bond
Peter Pan   Nothing happens here
```

Something simple as:

```
df[~df.var1.str.contains(df.var1)]
```

does not work. How I should write my python code?

Comment: James Bond still James Bond

Comment: A very simple solution would be to iterate over all rows and checking string.startswith(name) and then overwriting the row content with string[len(name):]

Comment: it's not in the beginning of the sentence @BENY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using apply lambda;

```
df["var1"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["var1"][len(x["name"]):].strip() if x["name"] == x["var1"][:len(x["name"])] else x["var1"],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df['var1'] = [df.loc[i, 'var1'].replace(df.loc[i, 'name'], "") for i in df.index]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to replace names only if string starts with the name... e.g. "My name is James Bond" shall remain as it is...

Comment: Yep, you're right. My mistake! Your solution will work in this case! :)

Comment: Yes, you're right Sachin Kohli